# Simple form bootstrap for rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using 'bootstrap-sass' and 'simple_form' gems on Rails 4. When I run this generator: **rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap** I get a message that says:"Be sure to have a copy of the Bootstrap stylesheet available on your
  application, you can get it on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap."

Why do I need a copy of the Bootstrap stylesheet and what is THE stylesheet? Doesn't the 'bootstrap-sass' gem handle that? I went to the link provided but got a 404 error. If anyone can kindly explain what I need to do it would be greatly appreciated! I am fairly new to Rails, so apologize in advance if it's not a very good question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the real link to [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Yes, the `bootstrap-sass` gem will include Bootstrap's javascript, CSS, and fonts into your application, just make sure you include them.

In your javascripts/application.js ([docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#javascript))

```
//= require bootstrap
```

Create a file, say master.css.scss and import the Bootstrap CSS and fonts like so ([docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#sass)):

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

When you specified the extension `--bootstrap` when installing simple_form, you essentially said, hey I have bootstrap and want my forms to be styled the way bootstrap styles them. It will also add the appropriate HTML to the form and inputs to adhere to Bootstrap. So it automatically generated the file `config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb`. Now when you create a form using `simple_form_for` (please read their [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)..they are very extensive), it will be styled like Bootstrap.

So, to sum it up, you *need* Bootstrap if you *want* your forms to be styled and set up, with Bootstrap html and css, like [Bootstrap forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). If you didn't want Bootstrap, you could have just ran the simple_form generator like this: `rails generate simple_form:install`.

Answer (score 0):

when you ran this code:

```
rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

you are integrating `simple_form` with `bootsrap`. and therefore, what the message is telling you is to add `bootstrap` to your `stylesheets` folder of your application. The `stylesheet` folder is where you keep your `css` files. Here is it's directory structure:

```
app/assets/stylesheets
```

bootstrap download comes with `css`, `javascripts`, and `fonts` folders. the bootstrap files inside the `css` folder will go under `app/assets/stylesheets`.

of course, if you are not using `bootstrap` in your project, then you are running the wrong generator. you should simply run:

```
rails generate simple_form:install
```

and not append `--bootstrap` to the generator.